# Retrieve js cookie using mage magento model php

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Created a cookie using javascript

```
function (c_name,value,exdays) {
value = source ;
c_name = "Cookie" ;
var exdate=new Date();
exdays = exdate.setTime(exdate.getTime() + (30*24*60*60*1000));
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;

});
```

Can i retrieve using Mage::getModel(‘core/cookie’)->get();   ??

Answer (score 0):

If you would look inside the class Mage_Core_Model_Cookie the definition for the method get is:

```
/**
 * Retrieve cookie or false if not exists
 *
 * @param string $neme The cookie name
 * @return mixed
 */
public function get($name = null)
{
    return $this->_getRequest()->getCookie($name, false);
}
```

The _getRequest() retreives an instance of Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http a class that extends Zend_Controller_Request_Http inside which the method getCookie is defined as:

```
/**
 * Retrieve a member of the $_COOKIE superglobal
 *
 * If no $key is passed, returns the entire $_COOKIE array.
 *
 * @todo How to retrieve from nested arrays
 * @param string $key
 * @param mixed $default Default value to use if key not found
 * @return mixed Returns null if key does not exist
 */
public function getCookie($key = null, $default = null)
{
    if (null === $key) {
        return $_COOKIE;
    }

    return (isset($_COOKIE[$key])) ? $_COOKIE[$key] : $default;
}
```

So yes, you can retrieve a cookie using Magento classes and methods, Zend or the $_COOKIE superglobal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access javascript cookies, in your case by using:

```
$cookieValue = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('Cookie');
```

Also, If it doesn't require that you set the cookie via JavaScript you can set it by:

```
/*
* ->set('name', 'value', 'expDate', 'path', 'domain', 'secure', 'httpsOnly')
* Only Name and Value are required. expDate set for 24 hours below.
*/
Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('Cookie', source, time()+86400);
```